# Implementing functor interface vs Funcion objects as members C++

Tags: c++, coding-style, performance

I'm currently writing a neural network implementation in c++ and a curios question occurred to me:

I want my NN to be "generic", therefore i want to be able to define custom transfer and error functions. My first instinct is to create an interface (abstract class) and pass derived objects as argument (basically functors):

```
class VectorizedFunction {
public:
    virtual MatrixXf  F(const Ref<MatrixXf>&) = 0;
    virtual MatrixXf dF(const Ref<MatrixXf>&) = 0;
    virtual ~VectorizedFunction() = 0;
}

class VTanh : public VectorizedFunction {
    MatrixXf  F(const Ref<MatrixXf>&){
        return M.array().tanh().matrix();
    }

    MatrixXf dF(const Ref<MatrixXf>&){
        auto th = M.array().tanh(); 
        return (1 - th*th).matrix();
    }
}
```

But then i reminded myself that function objects were introduced in C++11 letting me do things like:

```
class VectorizedFunction {
public:
    function<MatrixXf(const Ref<MatrixXf>&)> F;
    function<MatrixXf(const Ref<MatrixXf>&)> dF;
};

VectorizedFunction tf;
tf.F = [&](const Ref<MatrixXf>& M)->MatrixXf { return M.array().tanh().matrix(); };
tf.dF = [&](const Ref<MatrixXf>& M)->MatrixXf { auto th = M.array().tanh(); return (1 - th*th).matrix(); };
```

Which of the two options will produce less overhead and which will be easier to maintain?

Comment: `std::function` is not the only kind of function object, it is a *polymorphic* function object. anything with an `operator()` is a function object. Are you wishing to re-use specific functions in multiple `VectorizedFunction` objects?

Comment: Also: if none of your functions have state, you can use `typedef MatrixXf(*fp)(const Ref<MatrixXf>&);` to define a common function pointer type.

Comment: No, i don't plan to reuse function, i only need to set them once for my neural network. Also, is there any benefit when using function pointer instead of `function` template? Because is my mind the template does the same thing only with better syntax.

Comment: `std::function` generally involves another indirection over a function pointer, which makes it costlier to call, and hurts with the compilers ability to inline things (thus fewer further optimisations are provably valid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take a look at the pros and cons of a function-based approach:

### Pros:

- Flexibility - There is absolutely no doubt in this.  Any function can be passed will be called.  Of course deriving from an abstract class as in our other case is flexible as well, you're also obliging anyone wanting to have custom behavior to derive from that class which is a small limitation.  In short, they're both flexible, but this solution is moreso.
- User-friendly - If you're writing a library, this is conducive to better design as it allows the user of your library to essentially do whatever he or she wishes rather than obliging them to derive from a specific class.  Not a *big* deal per se, but I've known many programmers that were bothered by such things.

### Cons

- Maintainability - There is absolutely *nothing* tieing your `VectorizedFunction` to its implementation.  This isn't just loose coupling.  The thing is dangling beneath your feet like an extra appendage.  If you find a bug, you have to see how it is called to know where your implementation lies.  Whereas in the abstract class approach, you'd simply need to check all classes deriving from it which can be found simply by searching all code for `VectorizedFunction`.

Ultimately, it's your decision, but if I were writing it for my own purposes, I'd stick with the abstract class approach.  Otherwise, I think I would prefer to stick with the more flexible approach.  Hope that helps!